# Threats Against/At/Toward

Tags: prepositions, usage, collocations

I have a question about the preposition to use with "*threat*":

> 1. He made threats ***against*** her.
> 2. He made threats ***at*** her.
> 3. He made threats ***toward*** her.

Should it be "*against*", "*at*", or "*toward*"?

Comment: Also "threats on his/her life" is common.

Comment: What does your dictionary say?

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/threat?q=threat

Answer (score 1):

Out of those three, I think it's the first one with 'against'. Because you are using 'make' there.

[OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/threat#threat__4) gives us an example with it:

> to *make threats **against*** somebody

A headline from [CBS LA](http://losangeles.cbslocal.com/2013/09/10/hacker-used-incarcerated-mans-facebook-to-make-threat-against-antelope-valley-college/)

> Hacker Used Incarcerated Man’s Facebook To *Make Threat Against* Antelope Valley College

Comment: Also worth mentioning: *He threatened her.*

Comment: There couuld be many such examples. But I think we are concerned with 'make threats' with 'make' in it. @snailboat

Answer (score 1):

All three are possible, and well-attested.

Answer (score 0):

Each can mean something different (though the distinctions below might not always be strictly observed) and is valid with *to make a threat*:

> He made threats at her.

This implies that he was in the vincinity of her (he was "at" her).  *X at Y* means X and Y are in the same place.  So there's a chance this could mean something like he raised his fists and made a threatening gesture near her, but she may not have seen it because her back was turned.

> He made threats toward her.

This means that he said or did something in her direction.  It likely implies there was some distance between them and that the threat was not only verbal but may have involved a weapon or fists, etc.

*Toward* also might be used to express that A specifically targeted B out of a group.

> He made threats against her.

The other two sentences imply that the two are physically near or can at least physically see each other, if neither of these are true, *against* will work.  Also if the threat is something abstract or non-physical/verbal, *against* might be used.  For example, *He made a threat against her via email* or *The CEO resigned yesterday, which was a threat against the well-being of the company.*